# How to customize login page in AiryMVC PHP framework

Tags: authentication

We want to use AiryMVC default login mechanism. We use a LoginController to extend the AclController and the $loginForm is created by calling $this->_acl->login("loginForm").

```
Class LoginController extends AclController {
    public function userLoginAction()   {
           $this->_acl->login("loginForm");
    }
...
}
```

The view then has the $loginForm, but we want to style the login form. All the html tags can be put only outside of the form element $loginForm like below. How can we style the loginForm element?

```
<div>
    <?php echo $loginForm;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Forget to mention version 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form can use decoration - [refer this API](http://www.airymvc.com/doc.php?op=3). You can do that in the controller.

```
$formDecoration = array ("the_form_id" => array("<div class='abc'>", "</div>"));
$this->loginForm->setDecoration($formDecoration);
```